# Looking for Historical wind data (direction/speed) for E. Africa or greater

Tags: data, weather, africa

Does anybody know of  a source for wind data ~04 - 14 for E. Africa or a larger area. I have looked at a number of sources but have not found anything for these consecutive years.

Comment: You might want to move this to Open data here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ since this is not GIS technical related question. This is more of data request and Open data is where everyone asked data there.